# Side wide search engine using AWS Glue, S3 and Athena

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

We have ~30 microservices that has forum data, user data, ticket data, billing data, activity data, notifications and so on and so forth.  These data are in independent databases. End users would like to search for relevant data which will help them get to the information they need and this improves UX with our product.

Instead of using elasticsearch and building complex search systems, we were wondering if we could build a search engine using AWS Glue, S3, Athena / S3 select.

Multiple Glue jobs will periodically query the dbs for tables and columns that has user data and dump it to S3 in a compressed format - parquet. We will then query this data using S3 select when user searches for this data resulting in a low cost, poor mans search engine.

We are aware data will not be up-to-date in S3 which is acceptable. Most users do not query for the data immediately once modified.

We are not sure what is the latency to fetch the search results and the delay from a UX point of view.  Would like to hear technical feedback on this approach if there is a better way of doing this.